# Xpages radio button in a view

Tags: mobile, user-interface, xpages

I am using a standard view control in xpages which has a checkbox for selecting a number of documents which can then be processed. I would like to add a radio button (yes/no) selection for each document in the view. What's the best and easiest option to achieve this?

edited: what I am looking for is inline editing I guess in an xpages view to edit value of each document in a view using a radio button.

By the way it doesn't have to be a standard view control, I can change it to data tables or repeat controls if that will help me achieve this.

Comment: I wouldn't do that, according to UX practices. High count of radiobuttons is nightmare of UI, I think.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? is radio button the requirement?

Comment: There are going to be less than 10 docs in the view, never more and yes radio button is a requirement unfortunately!

Comment: This is Ecommerce app and these are repeat customers, so when they renew the service, I want to ask them a question for each item when they renew and let them answer in the form of yes/no.

Comment: What is your "transaction"? Will you have single Save button to update all documents in batch, or you want to update immediately after value change?

Comment: At the moment it updates all when a save button is pressed, but it can do a partial refresh (if you are thinking of partial refresh) and change these values for each document - that's not a problem at all.

Answer (score 1):

Could you simply use the Checkbox property in the view column?
[image: checkbox property on a view column]

Then you could also make use of the SSJS with something like this:

```
var viewPanel=getComponent("viewPanel1");get the componet of viewPanel
var docIDArray=viewPanel.getSelectedIds(); get the array of document ids
for(i=0;i < docIDArray.length; i++){
    var docId=docIDArray[i];
    var doc=database.getDocumentByID(docId); 
    //.. your code to deal with the selected document
}
```

Comment: Thanks Matt for the suggestion, I am already using this feature, but on top of this for each selected doc, I need to ask them a further question which is answered by ticking yes/no.

Comment: Ideally I don't want them to be taken to another page, I want to show them the radio button on the same page (in the same view) as the one they use the checkbox on, to select these documents.